# PDF to Html Conversion using API in java

Tags: java, aspose, pdf-to-html

I want to convert large PDF files to HTML with correct formatting even with image graphs.
I tried with [aspose](http://www.aspose.com/), but its converting only 2 pages from 10 page PDF file.
Please suggest me any good API in java to convert large PDF to HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aspose.Pdf can successfully convert multi-page PDF to HTML with precision without losing formatting. It seems like you are facing an evaluation restriction. You can get a [30 days temporary license](http://www.aspose.com/corporate/purchase/temporary-license.aspx) for evaluation purpose. If you still face the issue, share your pdf file for further testing.

Check the following code regarding how to apply the [license](http://www.aspose.com/corporate/purchase/temporary-license.aspx).

```
com.aspose.pdf.License lic = new com.aspose.pdf.License();                                         
lic.setLicense("C:\\data\\Aspose.Total.Java.lic");                                                 

com.aspose.pdf.Document pdfDoc=new com.aspose.pdf.Document("D:/Naazneen/files/images.pdf");        
pdfDoc.save("C:/Users/naazneen.b/Documents/images.html",com.aspose.pdf.SaveFormat.Html);
```

Hope this will resolve the issue at your end.

P.S. I work as Social Media Developer at Aspose.

Answer (score 0):

When I was at university I converted some of my documents for my course/project using a [online converter](http://www.idrsolutions.com/online-pdf-to-html5-converter/) at IDRSolutions. I think that they also have a API, I just took a quick look on the website and I found this [30 day trial](http://www.idrsolutions.com/pdf2html2-trial-downloads/).  I hope this helps you out :)